# SQL query to select a view with a null column

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have `table1` with columns `A , B , C` and another one, `table2` with columns `A, D`.

I want to create a view to show columns `A, B, C, D` and there should be all values of column `A` even if there is no `A` in `table2`

I tried:

```
select 
    a, b, c, d 
from 
    table 1 
inner join 
    table 2 where table1.a = table2.a
```

suggest something

Comment: Rob Paller thank you so much......... it worked :d cheers....

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use an OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t2.d 
FROM table t1 
  LEFT JOIN table t2 
    ON t1.a = t2.a;
```